# JavaScript: How can i transpile array forEach, map, filter and etc to 'for' loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I wrote a code in valid es5, but some old enterprise system can't eat it as a module, it falls on 'array.forEach'. I don't now why, may be it runs some tests from the 90's or what else.

Is it posible to transpile it via babel or typescript?

```
// When this...
const a = ['abc', 'defghi'];
const b = a.filter(z => z.length > 3).forEach(z => console.log(z));

// ... becomes something like that
var a = ['abc', 'defghi'];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].length > 3)  {
        b.push(a[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    console.log(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add polyfills? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill

Comment: When using typescript, change the target to 'es3' in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: I think i will use polyfills if it's impossible to transpile this code.
Also i've tried with typescript.

I've created an index.js file with content like in description.

Created config ts.config;

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es3",
        "removeComments": true,
        "outFile": ".build/index.js",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "files": [
        "index.js"
    ]
}


But it only transpiles const to var and lambda to function

Comment: Any reason not to load a polyfill like es5-shim instead? That would make sure those methods exist.

Comment: @loganfsmyth the polyfill is even slower than native, and native is already too slow - http://glat.info/transfun/test.html#speed-test 
We should all be transpiling our map().reduce() to loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), a library that use methods pretty similar to those ES5 you're trying to use. You can make something `_.map([2,3,4], function(item) { console.log(item] })`

Comment: Unfortunatly, i can't use any libs, only pure javascript